# ¿Cómo hacer que mi canción de fondo reproduzca infinitamente?

Tags: html5, loops

> Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type audio/mp3:

Esto me dice la consola al estar en ejecución y mi canción de fondo suena pero no repite, luego de la duración de la canción la página se queda sin música y es algo incómodo

Este es mi código

```
<! DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="icono.png"/>
<embed src="T.mp3" hidden=true loop=true></embed>
```

Answer (score 3):

Usa la etiqueta `audio` con el atributo `loop` sin asignar un valor, en lugar de `embed` ya que este último es para plug-ins, no para archivos de audio.

Ejemplo de https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/audio al que se le agregó el atributo `loop`. Nota: Sea paciente para escuchar la repetición, probado en Chrome versión 60 para Windows 64-bits.

```html
<audio src="http://developer.mozilla.org/@api/deki/files/2926/=AudioTest_(1).ogg"
       autoplay loop>
  Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> element.
</audio>
```